# ASP.Net MVC Web does not validate empty fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use Visual Studio 2013, Update 5

with the ASP.NET MVC Project Template I created a simple Web to get deeper into MVC after taking a few steps.

I added a Model for which i creaded a standard Edit View and Controller.

In my Model I use "Required" and MinLength Attributes.
The MinLength Attibutes raised Validation Messages but if the Fields are kept empty the "Required" Attributes doesn't work.

What works is, if I just put one Character in the field, and leave the field (so that the MinLenth Validation Fails) and afterwards Clear the complete field.
Only in this Case, the Required Attribute seems to do anythings.
(Bug or Feature?! :-) )

Here is the Model I use with the Edit View completely generated by "new View" Template of Visual Studio

```
public class Apotheke
  {
    [DisplayName("Apotheken Nr.")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:D4}")]
    [Range(1, 9999)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public int ApothekenNr { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name der Apotheke")]
    [MinLength(3)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
    public string ApoName { get; set; }

    [MinLength(3)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Straße { get; set; }

    [MinLength(5)]
    [MaxLength(5)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string PLZ { get; set; }

    [MinLength(3)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Ort { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Inhaber Vorname")]
    [MinLength(3)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Vorname { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Inhaber Nachname")]
    [MinLength(3)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public string Nachname { get; set; }


    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [MinLength(10)]
    [MaxLength(10)]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    public DateTime Eintritt { get; set; }

  }
```

Comment: have you tried this [Required] ?

Comment: Without using AllowEmptyStrings=false ,this should work  [Required]

Comment: Not related, but `[Required]` on your `int ApothekenNr`and `DateTime Eintritt` properties is not necessary (type of `int` and `DateTime` can't be `null` so its always required)

Comment: yes, I tried [Required] (so without AllowEmptyStrings=false) and also tried AllowEmptyStrings=true out of desperation

Comment: plz show your view code and controller code , may be something is missing there

Comment: From you edit, you may be confused how client side validation works. It's lazy, meaning if you start with an empty field and just tab through it (or even add a character and then backspace), validation is not triggered until you submit the form. Its only when the value is changed and you tab out that immediate validation is triggered. Note also that only one message is displayed so you may just be seeing the message associated with `MinLength` (its not really necessary to add `[Required]` if you have `[MinLength]` anyway)

Comment: @StephanMuecke: I do not start with an Empty field. In the Edit View, I have a proper Value in the Field. If I reduce it to one Character the "MinLenth" Validation is triggered. If i mark all, and delete all (without triggering the MinValue Validation before) the "Required" Validation is not triggered

Answer (score 2):

`AllowEmptyStrings = false` raises a validation error when user enters blank spaces. It is working fine in below framework. Please try validating object in controller to make sure your annotations are correct. Check `ModelState` errors.

To test your issue I am using below packages on .NET 4.5 (VS 2013, MVC 5):

- "EntityFramework" version="6.1.3"
- "jQuery" version="2.1.4"
- "jQuery.Validation" version="1.11.1"

  ```
  public ActionResult Edit(string id)
  {
      ...
      returningModel.PLZ = "  ";
      //returningModel.PLZ = null;

      bool b = TryValidateModel(returningModel); 
      var modelStateErrors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(m => m.Errors);
      return View(returningModel);
  }
  ```